# In Java, how do I reference the parent/sibling object of a class if they are not related by extension?

Tags: java

I'm really confused about this subject, so please help me out. Searching on the internet gave some description about class and parent class. However, I'm more interested in "parent object" not a class that extends another class (inheritance).

Let's say I have the following code for the Parent class:

```
public class ParentContainer extends JPanel 
{
    public Child1Container myChild1 = new Child1Container();
    public Child2Container myChild2 = new Child2Container();

    public ParentContainer() {
        JLabel lblParent = new JLabel("I'm the parent");
        add(lblParent);

        add(myChild1);
        add(myChild2);

        JLabel lblParentReceiver = new JLabel("Awaiting message from child...");
        add(lblParentReceiver);

        //I'm going to give child 1 a call...
        JButton btnParentToChild1 = new JButton("Parent: Hello Child 1!");
        btnParentToChild1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JLabel child1Reicever = myChild1.lblChild1Receiver;
                child1Receiver.setText("Parent Says: Hello Child 1?");
            }
        });
        add(btnChild1ToParent);
    }
}
```

And the following code for the Child1 Class:

```
public class Child1Container extends JPanel 
{
    public JLabel lblChild1Receiver = new JLabel("Awaiting message from parent...");

    public Child1Container() {
        JLabel lblChild1 = new JLabel("I'm child 1");
        add(lblChild1);

        //I'm waiting for my parent to give me a call...
        add(lblChild1Receiver);

        //I tried to call my parent, but he can't hear me :(
        JButton btnChild1ToParent = new JButton("Child1: Hello Parent!");
        btnChild1ToParent.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JLabel parentReceiver = this.getParent().lblParentReceiver;
                parentReceiver.setText("Child1: Hello Parent!");
            }
        });
        add(btnChild1ToParent);

        //I tried to call my sibling, but he can't hear me either :(
        JButton btnChild1ToSibling = new JButton("Child1: Hello Child2!");
        btnChild1ToSibling.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JLabel child2Receiver = getParent().myChild2.lblChild2Receiver;
                child2Receiver.setText("Child1: Hello Child2!");
            }
        });
        add(btnChild1ToSibling);
    }
}
```

And the following code for Child2 Class:

```
public class Child2Container extends JPanel 
{
    public JLabel lblChild2Receiver = new JLabel("Awaiting message from sibling...");

    public Child2Container() {
        JLabel lblChild2 = new JLabel("I'm child 2");
        add(lblChild2);

        //I'm waiting for my sibling to give me a call... I feel so alone :(
        add(lblChild2Receiver);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's a lonely digital world out there. In a family of `JPanel` containers, no one is able to talk to one another, except for maybe the parent to child.
Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish the child (contained) object to be able to communicate with the parent (container), you can pass a reference of the parent to the child's constructor :

```
public Child1Container(JPanel parent) {
    ...
    this.parent = parent;
    ...
}
```

Then the child can call any public method of the parent.

You can have a method in the ParentContainer class :

```
public void callSiblings (JPanel from, String message)
{
    // sends message to all the children except of the sender child
}
```

Then a child can call that method and send a message to its siblings :

```
this.parent.callSiblings (this, "hello brother!");
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed it. I was hoping there was some way to reference "parent" like in HTML elements. I will flag this as answered! Thanks for the quick response.